# Back button on Django

Tags: django, request

I am trying to use HTTP_REFERER to create a link to the previous page. However, let's say I have a 'page1' that calls the 'page2' get method. It will show a form at the 'page2' where I can do a post request. When I post on the 'page2', the HTTP_REFERER is referencing the same page (page2), therefore I can't to back to the 'page1'. Is there anything I can do to go back to the 'page1'?

Comment: Going back to previous page after post request: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796195/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-in-django-after-post-request)

Comment: It won't work, because the request is coming from the same page.

Comment: This will work. The method is setting an additional hidden field on your form which captures the referring url. The post request will then be on the same page, and you redirect to that hidden field which was the url before that.

Comment: The next attribute keeps pointing to the current URL, even though I used <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}">.  My guess is that {{ request.path }} is loading the request path of the GET method that I did before the post.

Comment: The value for the next url should be your HTTP_REFERER

Comment: Oh....sure! I didn't realize it. Create an answer that I will take as accepted. Thanks

Comment: I read this, for a back button/link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524992/how-to-implement-a-back-link-on-django-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a hidden next field to your form . This will capture the previous page by making use of the HTTP_REFERER. After your post request you can then perform a redirect to the page you were on before the form page.

Edit:
More information can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796195/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-in-django-after-post-request).