# how to return redirect to previous page in Django after POST request

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm coding a news website,in the detail news page ,there is a comment fountain,if people want to post comment they need to login first.And I want to make it that,after they login in successfully ,the page can return to previous news page.

Here is my views.py:

```
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    news = News.objects.get(id=news_pk)
    title = news.title
    author = news.author_name
    add_time = news.add_time
    content = news.content
    category = news.category
    tags = news.tag.annotate(news_count=Count('news'))

    all_comments = NewsComments.objects.filter(news=news)

    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST' and comment_form.is_valid():
        comments = comment_form.cleaned_data.get("comment")
        comment = NewsComments(user=request.user, comments=comments, news=news)
        comment.save()

    return render(request, "news_detail.html", {
        'title': title,
        'author': author,
        'add_time': add_time,
        'content': content,
        'tags': tags,
        'category': category,
        'all_comments': all_comments,
        'comment_form': comment_form
    })
```

Here is my news_detail.html:

```
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"><h5>评论 <i class="fa fa-comments"></i></h5>
                                </label>
                                <textarea id="js-pl-textarea" class="form-control" rows="4"
                                          placeholder="我就想说..." name="comment"></textarea>
                                <div class="text-center mt-3">
                                    <input type="submit" id='js-pl-submit' class="btn btn-danger comment-submit-button" value="Submit Comemmt">
                                    </input>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>


                    {% else %}   
                   <span>Please Login or register first</span>                         
                            <a class="btn btn-primary mb-5"
                                                         href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">登录</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger mb-5" href="{% url 'register' %}?next={{ request.path }}">注册</a>

                    {% endif %}
```

Here is my LoginView:

```
class LoginView(View):

def get(self, request):
    return render(request, "login.html", {})

def post(self, request):
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if login_form.is_valid():
        user_name = request.POST.get("username", "")
        pass_word = request.POST.get("password", "")
        user = authenticate(username=user_name, password=pass_word)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
            else:
                return render(request, "login.html", {"msg": "用户未激活！"})
        else:
            return render(request, "login.html", {"msg": "用户名或密码错误！"})
    else:
        return render(request, "login.html", {"login_form": login_form})
```

And I have a login.html and register.html.They works very well.

Anybody know how to make it in my particular case?Thank you so much!

Comment: What is the vieew the user was before going to `newsdetailsView`? you meant that you want to redirect the user to the view he was before posting a comment?

Comment: yes.The before going to newsdetailView, the user is in index.html,view is  newsList,and then they come to the newsdetailView,there is a comment function here,if they want to post comment they need to login in ,so they will go to loginView,after login ,they should redirect to newsdetailView where they wanted to post a comment.

Comment: is that working with the answer of @HenryM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
    request.session['login_from'] = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/')
```

Second:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    #TODO: 
    #Redirect to previous url
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.session['login_from'])
```

Comment: awesome, this is safer and no packages needed... +1.

Comment: @Lemayzeur Hi man I just post another question about Django could you help me with it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013581/ajax-not-work-in-django-post?noredirect=1#comment87043510_50013581  ?

Comment: I don't think this will work all the time. What if user browser is set to work in private/incognito mode and by default than referer is disabled, so it will fail. I think better solution might be to use hidden input in template inside form tag like:
`<input id="full_path" name="full_path" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}">`
And call that value afterwards in view like this to redirect to previous:
`return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('full_path'))`

Answer (score 3):

`return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))` will return you to the page that called the current function.

Comment: this is a little untrusted, the user can refresh the page, and `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` will be `None`

Comment: Really appreciate for your help,but I add another part of your answer:    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.session['login_from']).And then it works.

Answer (score 3):

You send the the current path via `next` parameter

```
<span>Please Login or register first</span>                         
    <a class="btn btn-primary mb-5" href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">登录</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger mb-5" href="{% url 'register' %}?next={{ request.path }}">注册</a>
</span>
```

so in your loginView or RegisterView;

retrieve the parameter `next` once you're done with all the processes, and you are ready to redirect the user, for instance it can be after submitting a form.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, Resolver404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect

url = request.GET.get("next")
try:
    resolve(url)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
except Resolver404: # Make sure the url comes from your project
    return redirect("default_view") # A default view
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.But for this method I still need install resolve package.And I find a easier way and it works.Please check my answer.

Comment: What did you end up using?

Comment: I just post it out.Please check my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completion, in case you would like to create a clickable back-link in an HTML-document (i.e. any given page), employ one of the following options:

**1.)** Works for all browsers

```
<input type=button value="Previous Page" onClick="window.history.back();return false;">
```

**2.)** javascript - version

```
<input type=button value="Previous Page" onClick="javascript:history.go(-1);">
```

[This answer and associated comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/666407/12298276) is where I found the two alternatives.

Note that instead of using `<input>` you can also use an `<a>`-tag e.g. like so (see [this thread](https://www.xspdf.com/help/50689214.html)):

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="btn btn-default">Previous Page</a>
```