# Ajax not work in Django post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-views

I'm trying to use ajax in Django to post comment in a news website.However it doesn't work.**When I click the submit button,it still refreshes the page and make no difference like no ajax.**

I'm really new in Django and Ajax.Any friend can help me solve it?

Here is my view.py:

```
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    news = News.objects.get(id=news_pk)
    title = news.title
    author = news.author_name
    add_time = news.add_time
    content = news.content
    category = news.category
    tags = news.tag.annotate(news_count=Count('news'))

    all_comments = NewsComments.objects.filter(news=news)

    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and comment_form.is_valid():
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {})
        comments = comment_form.cleaned_data.get("comment")
        news_comment = NewsComments(user=request.user, comments=comments, news=news)
        news_comment.save()

    return render(request, "news_detail.html", {
        'title': title,
        'author': author,
        'add_time': add_time,
        'content': content,
        'tags': tags,
        'category': category,
        'all_comments': all_comments,
        'comment_form': comment_form
    })
```

Here is my news_detail template where I get form data:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form id="js-pl-submit" method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in comment_form %}
{% for error in field.errors %}
<div class="alert alert-warning text-center mb-3" role="alert">{{ error }}</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here in my news_detail template I render all the comments to the template:

```
 {% for user_comments in all_comments %}
<img class="mr-3 comment-avatar rounded-circle"src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ user_comments.user.image }}"alt="Generic placeholder image">
<div class="media-body">
<h6 class="mt-0 mb-1">{{ user_comments.user.username }}</h6>
{{ user_comments.comments }}
</div>
<span>{{ user_comments.add_time }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my Ajax in news_detail template:

```
$('#js-pl-submit').on('click', function(){
    var comments = $("#js-pl-textarea").val()
    if(comments == ""){
        alert("评论不能为空")
        return false
    }
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url:"",
        data:{'news_pk':{{ news.id }}, 'comments':comments},
        async: true,
        beforeSend:function(xhr, settings){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status == 'fail'){
                if(data.msg == '用户未登录'){
                    window.location.href="login";
                }else{
                    alert(data.msg)
                }
            }else if(data.status == 'success'){
                window.location.reload();//刷新当前页面.
            }
        },
    });
    return false;
});
```

Finally here is my form.py of the comment.

```
def words_validator(comment):
    if len(comment) < 4:
        raise ValidationError("亲，最少写两个字")


class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), validators=[words_validator])
```

Comment: `it doesn't work` Please elaborate, or it will be near impossible to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Your `url:""` parameter is empty.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you for your reply the issue is :When I click the submit button,it still refreshes the page and make no difference like no ajax.

Comment: @5740382 yes,but I'm posting the data to this page itself,so I think I just need let the url empty,is this right?

Comment: Id didn't find the button code in above snippet. problem might be your button's button type is submit change it to button

Answer (score 1):

Add click event on `button` not on `form` and You have to change that to `button` implicitly.
By default the type of a `button` is submit.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<button type="button" id="js-pl-submit">
```

Remove `id` of form.
Submit button submits form-data and reload the page.

Comment: Hi could you please me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145502/django-filter-exclude-foreign-key Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your binding is incorrect, you have the click handler on the form it should be a submit handler. If you were binding it to a button then you'd use click a handler.

```
$('#js-pl-submit').on('submit', function(){//<-- here
    var comments = $("#js-pl-textarea").val()
    if(comments == ""){
        alert("评论不能为空")
        return false
    }
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url:"",
        data:{'news_pk':{{ news.id }}, 'comments':comments},
        async: true,
        beforeSend:function(xhr, settings){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status == 'fail'){
                if(data.msg == '用户未登录'){
                    window.location.href="login";
                }else{
                    alert(data.msg)
                }
            }else if(data.status == 'success'){
                window.location.reload();//刷新当前页面.
            }
        },
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Finally I made it!Thanks Lord!Very excited!Please check my detailed answer here:Django Ajax Form submit wrongly redirect to another page really appreciate everyone's reply!With your reply I figured out these issue step by step!

Comment: Hi could you please me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145502/django-filter-exclude-foreign-key Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi friend can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159365/reverse-for-news-detail-with-arguments-not-found-1-patterns-tried ?

Answer (score 1):

This could work, it contains some suggestions from your codes.

> ++ newsDetailView
>   ++ in news_details.html
>   ++ in you scripts

**views.py**

```
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    #news = News.objects.get(id=news_pk) No need to get the object like this anymore
    news = get_object_or_404(News,id=news_pk) #
    title = news.title
    author = news.author_name
    add_time = news.add_time
    content = news.content
    category = news.category
    tags = news.tag.annotate(news_count=Count('news'))

    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and comment_form.is_valid():
        # if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax() and comment_form.is_valid(): To make sure it's ajax
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return JsonResponse({"msg":"You need to login",
            "url":'login_url','status':'login_required'})
        comments = comment_form.cleaned_data.get("comment")
        news_comment = NewsComments(user=request.user, comments=comments, news=news)
        news_comment.save()

    # This needs to be after request.POST process 
    all_comments = NewsComments.objects.filter(news=news) 

    context = {
        'title': title,
        'author': author,
        'add_time': add_time,
        'content': content,
        'tags': tags,
        'category': category,
        'all_comments': all_comments,
        'comment_form': comment_form,
    }   
    return render(request, "news_detail.html", context)
```

**news_detail.html** | Form

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form id="js-pl-submit" method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in comment_form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning text-center mb-3" role="alert">{{ error }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
{% endif %}
```

**news_detail.html** | Comments

```
<div id="comments_section">
    {% for user_comments in all_comments %}
    <img class="mr-3 comment-avatar rounded-circle" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ user_comments.user.image }}" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0 mb-1">{{ user_comments.user.username }}</h6>
        {{ user_comments.comments }}
    </div>
    <span>{{ user_comments.add_time }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**JS script**

```
$(document).on('submit','#js-pl-submit',function(){ // Correction : Not click, but submit
    var comments = $("#js-pl-textarea").val()
    if(!comments){
        alert("评论不能为空")
        return false
    }
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url:"",
        data:{
            // 'news_pk':{{ news.id }}, No need to send the news.id
            /// you are actually on the instance of `news` Object 
            'comments':comments,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(), // retrieve `csrf_token` from `form`
        },
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            // Not sure it's the more powerful, but this should work like a charm
            if(data.status == 'login_url'){
                alert(data.msg);
                window.location.href = data.url;
            }
            // Those 2 next lines are useful if you want to refresh without reload the page.
            $("#js-pl-submit").replaceWith($('#js-pl-submit',data));//刷新当前页面.
            $("#comments_section").replaceWith($('#comments_section',data));
            // This next line will reload the page
            windows.location.reload();

        },
        error:function(){
            // Codes here in case of error
        },
        statusCode:{
            404:function(){
                alert("Object not found");
            },
            500:function(){
                alert("An error has occured on the server");
            },
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Feel free to comment, so that I can edit my answer, to help you succeed.

Comment: Finally I made it!Thanks Lord!Very excited!Please check my detailed answer here:Django Ajax Form submit wrongly redirect to another page really appreciate everyone's reply!With your reply I figured out these issue step by step!

Comment: glad to be of help!

Comment: Hi could you please me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145502/django-filter-exclude-foreign-key Thank you so much!

Comment: I'll check it out for sure

Comment: Thank you so much friend!Another master has solved it.But I think the solution maybe will be helpful for you!

Comment: Thank you! for your further questions, you're free to tag me in comments... :)

Comment: No problem!Appreciate so much!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it!Thanks Lord!Very excited!Please check my detailed answer here:[Django Ajax Form submit wrongly redirect to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051635/django-ajax-form-submit-wrongly-redirect-to-another-page/50077689#50077689.I) really appreciate everyone's reply!With your reply I figured out these issue step by step!