# Django filter exclude foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm creating a news website which has two models:

1. News
2. BestNews.

*BestNews* has a foreign key of *News*.

News stands for all the news and BestNews is stands for the recommended news.

Now I have rendered News list and Best News list in index.html.But some news in these two parts are duplicated.

I hope news that in Best News list, will not appear in News list, and once I have removed the news from the Best News in admin, the news which has been removed from best news will appear News list.

Here is my News model:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='标题') 
    content = UEditorField(verbose_name="内容", width=600, height=300, imagePath="news/ueditor/", filePath="news/ueditor/", default='')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "新闻"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is my Best News model:

```
class Best(models.Model):
    select_news = models.ForeignKey(News, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='select_news',verbose_name='要闻')  
    SELECT_REASON = (
        ('左一', '左一'),
        ('左二', '左二'),
    )
    select_reason = models.CharField(choices=SELECT_REASON, max_length=50, null=False)  

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "精选"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.select_reason + '-' + self.select_news.title
```

Here is my News list view:I get News list and Best News list in one view.

```
class NewsView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        all_news = News.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
        bestnews1 = Best.objects.filter(select_reason="左一")[0].select_news
        bestnews2 = Best.objects.filter(select_reason="左二")[0].select_news
      
        return render(request, 'index.html', {
            'all_news': news,
             'bestnews1':bestnews1,
             'bestnews2':bestnews1,
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
all_news = News.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
```

to

```
all_news = News.objects.filter(select_news__isnull=True).order_by('-pk')
```

---

free advice:

change

```
bestnews1 = Best.objects.filter(select_reason="左一")[0].select_news
```

to

```
bestnews1 = Best.objects.filter(select_reason="左一").first()
bestnews1_new = None if bestnew1 is None else bestnews1.select_news
return render(request, 'index.html', {
            'all_news': news,
             'bestnews1_new':bestnews1_new,
             'bestnews2_new':bestnews2_new,
        })
```

Comment: The duplication gone, but once I removed the news from Best news in admin, error says:IndexError at /
list index out of range
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.0.4
Exception Type: IndexError
Exception Value: 
list index out of range

Comment: O I got it!That is because, no other best news there!Thank you very much!!

Comment: I have solved it.I think just because after I remove the best news ,there is no best news there, so    bestnews1 = Best.objects.filter(select_reason="左一")[0].select_news can't get any data.But after I put another best news there, errors gone.

Comment: May I ask how I use bestnews1_new  in the template? for example:{{bestnews1_new }}?I mean where to put it?

Comment: bestnews1_new is the bestnews1 you want,i just change the variable name.

Comment: Got you!!You are really awesome!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170254/discussion-between-william-and-ykh).

Comment: Hi friend could you help with my latest question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51899546/how-to-render-data-to-a-included-a-html-template-in-django