# How to make a Django return button point to the correct previous page?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, redirect

I have a page (**a.html**) that the user may reach from different other pages in my Django application. And in this page there is a *return button* to return to the previous page.

For instance:

- Page **b.html** contains a link to a view that presents **a.html**
- Page **c.html** contains a link to a view that presents **a.html**

I need to implement a way of making the *return button* point to the correct view (**b.html** or **c.html**), depending on how it was reached.

- **Fact 1**: I can't simply put an action `window.history.back();` because I need to reload the view it came from

**Edit 1**:

Using `request.META.HTTP_REFERER` does not work for me. Page a.html actually is a list of objects. And I can click in one of these objects and go to a third page (let's say: D.html) where I can edit the particular object and save. When you save it, the view redirects to the a.html page. And now, with this solution you mentioned, when I click in the return button, it does not return to the page I want (b.html or c.html) but fot the page I edited the item (d.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524992/django-templates-create-a-back-link

Use `request.META.HTTP_REFERER`

Comment: Make sure what you call a fact is actually one! You can listen to certain events (like history changes) and do the reload in JS.

Comment: @Huskell this solution does not work for me. Page a.html actually is a list of objects. And I can click in one of these objects and go to a third page (let's say: D.html) where I can edit the particular object and save. When you save it, the view redirects to the a.html page. And now, with this solution you mentioned, when I click in the return button, it does not return to the page I want (b.html or c.html) but fot the page I edited the item (d.html).

Comment: Add a boolean in the context and if it's True then trigger `window.history.back();`.

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute `onClick="javascript:history.go(-1);"`

Example: `<a onClick="javascript:history.go(-1);">Home</a>`

In my example, when I click "Home", it returns me to the homepage, but it also works with other situations.